# spotify permanent SP_ERROR_UNABLE_TO_CONTACT_SERVER on login

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I am trying to implement a client for spotify using libspotify library. Starting from some point I am receiving  SP_ERROR_UNABLE_TO_CONTACT_SERVER in login callback. Prior to this time, everything worked fine with the same codebase. Did anyone face the same problem? What could be the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

A common cause of this is not memset-ing your `sp_session_config` struct to zero before using it. This causes the proxy fields to be filled with garbage data, meaning the library will try to connect to an invalid proxy.

Always declare your libspotify structs like this:

```
sp_session_config config;
memset(&config, 0, sizeof(config));
```